# @Html exists, but ActionLink is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have started using VS 2015 from a previous version.

When I loaded the project, I'm missing many helpers such as

```
@ViewBag
@Html.ActionLink
```

`@Html` is recognised by intellisence, but not the `ActionLink`

In my web.config (in the root) I have

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Why do I have no `ActionLink`?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to MVC5 resolved the issue as I was previously on MVC4